# Ground question

Tags: audio, ground

Beginner here. I am working on a project using a Sure amplifier and noticed there is a ground label on one of the holes used for mounting. Do I need to do anything special for this? The link below shows the pcb and the bottom right mount hole with the ground symbol.

([Source](http://www.sureelectronics.net/gallery.php?id=12&img=8807))

[image]

Comment: I would wait for someone to confirm, but it may mean that you can/must connect it to the enclosure (assuming you are putting it into a metallic one) to have it at 0V.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that this is the [2 x 15W amplifier](http://www.sureelectronics.net/goods.php?id=1580).  If so, the **Notice** section details the proper use of the GND terminal:

> GND should be connected to GND or the housing of your instrument.