# AOZ1014AI Vout problem 0.8V instead of 6.5V

Tags: dc-dc-converter

My input voltage is 7.4 and I need to step it down to 6.5 with a 3A current. I've used an xls file from the supplier to calculate the followin scheme: [image]

I might made some mistake in my PCB here:

[image]

But it doesn't work. It gives just 0,8V on Vout.

Here are the calculation results:
[image]
[image]

EDITED:
I've read the circuit notes in the datasheet and done some changes. Do you think this circuit can work? 
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure whether this would be enough to cause the regulator to fail, but that is a pretty bad layout for an SMPS. Take a look into app notes and eval kits, but in essence: keep switching loops small, power traces fat and short, key components (capacitors, inductors, diodes) should be carefully placed.

Comment: It is already tiny enough. I can’t imaging it is possible to make it shorter with chip pins placed this way.

Comment: The traces are long and thin. Tiny PCB != short traces.

Comment: Not sure it could give such a drop of voltage.

Comment: It really could. You only need a fraction of a volt error on a feedback pin to completely mess up the regulation and protection circuitry. This explanation may help. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67894/use-of-ground-symbols-in-circuit-diagrams/67936#67936 A good way to re-lay out the board would be to use a 2-layer PCB with the entire second layer as a ground plane.

Comment: Seems it is a very sensitive chip. Even a touch can change the output voltage. Is it worth to use it with two servos as a step down dc-dc converter?

Comment: Please specify **D**. This better should be a fast recovery diode.

Comment: I have this one: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2119784.pdf

Comment: Thanks to everyone! You’ve been right. The way I’ve designed the first PCB is the cause. I’ve done it in a way I published later with wide and short traces and now it works just perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve made a new design for the board with fat traces and short loops and it works perfectly.

Comment: Cool! Is it the circuit that you posted on your edit?